How to apply CSS to musical accidentals?
This is in a small html file:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
...
<p>html code: C&#9839; C&#9837; C&#9838; or paste: sharp (C♯), flat (C♭), natural (C♮)</p>

In FF on PC both ways look fine. But in Android and Safari the Flat and Natural are badly kerned in all fonts I tried. To debug this I removed all font-family specifications and added color in CSS:
p {color:red;}

In FF/PC everything is red but elsewhere the Sharp is red but Flat and Natural stay black.

Does this mean that in Android and Safari #9837 #9838 do not render in the default font but #9839 does so?
What font should I use to render the three accidentals on the three platforms?

(NB I'm aware of all kinds of sofisticated solutions (html5, xml) but I have allready automated the writing of the html's so a pure CSS solution is welcomed)
(NB2 in the newest version of Safari all three are red but the bad kerning stays the same)

These notation characters are not included in most fonts thus, each browser render these in different symbol fonts. For a consistent rendering you should opt for a dedicated musical notation font - maybe something like https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Music

herrstrietzel: tnx I am aware of that but it is not the cross platform solution I am looking for. FYI: the code above and this "sharp (C♯), flat (C♭), natural (C♮)" renders all right in FF and Safari (even old ones)

Pardon me, but it still appears to be a "cross-browser" issue just because other browsers will use different symbol fonts to cover these not (by default) included glyphs – obviously screwing up somtething like tracking/kerning (especially kerning only works within one font-family)

herrstriezel: IMHO it is a cross browser issue because different browsers use different default fonts. So the trick is to find on each device a good font and use that with font-face (maybe with device dependent CSS). As you will see below on this forum there seems a good font available for Safari + accidentals.

After some debugging my 'answer to self' is: avoid using accidentals in UTF-8. The high codepages are not consistently implemented on different platforms.
In chord symbols the Natural is not needed. With this CSS the result looks fine for ASCII '#' and 'b' if you don't need italic elsewhere (otherwise use a class):
p { font-size: 13px;}
i { font-size: 10px;}

... or other convenient relative or absolute sizes depending on the font-family.
With this CSS, HTML chord symbols are looking good on PC, Android and iPad:
A<i>#</i>7  B<i>b</i>6

